# VisualState storyboard applies to resource instead of control?

Tags: wpf, xaml, storyboard, visualstatemanager, coloranimation

I have a weird problem with a storyboard inside a button visual state manager. I have two buttons with the same style and a specific `Foreground`. The `Path` that is the content of the button binds its `Fill` property to this foreground.

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleListNavigation}"
        Foreground="{DynamicResource NavigationButtonForegroundBrush}">
  <Button.Content>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource LeftArrowPath}"
          Fill="{Binding RelativeSource=
                         {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button},
                         Path=Foreground}" />
  </Button.Content>
</Button>

<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleListNavigation}"
        Foreground="{DynamicResource NavigationButtonForegroundBrush}">
  <Button.Content>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource RightArrowPath}"
          Fill="{Binding RelativeSource=
                         {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button},
                         Path=Foreground}" />
  </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

In their normal state the buttons look like this:

[image: Buttons normal]

The style `ButtonStyleListNavigation` is as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleListNavigation" TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <Border>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
              <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty=
                                "(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Chocolate" />
                  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
              <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

          <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" />
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

So when the user mouseovers one button, it's color should change, pretty straightforward. However, what happens when I mouseover *one* button is this:

[image: Buttons mouseover]

**Both** buttons change their color. I'm obviously doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the `Foreground` property of both buttons to the same SolidColorBrush instance (as given by the resource `NavigationButtonForegroundBrush`). Then in your ColorAnimation you change the `Color` property of that SolidColorBrush by the expression `(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)`. Obviously now both buttons have their `Foreground` changed.

You can prevent this by not using the brush as a resource but just its color. So the buttons should change to:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyleListNavigation}">
  <Button.Foreground>
    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource NavigationButtonForegroundColor}" />
  </Button.Foreground>
  <Button.Content>
    <Path Data="{StaticResource LeftArrowPath}"
          Fill="{Binding RelativeSource=
                         {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Button},
                         Path=Foreground}" />
  </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So I have to change the entire brush instead of just the color of the brush?

Comment: Or I could stop using the `Brush` resource.

Comment: Just saw your edit, which is exactly what i was about to post right now. Seems to be the right approach after all.

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction. I first tried replacing the entire brush using `ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames` but that didn't seem to work. In the end, simply not using the brush resource was even simpler.